# how to run animation effect when i scroll

Tags: css

I need to do a animation effect of running when i scroll on to a second page and do not run all at once. A example is [here](http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/)  on i need to work. I am a amateur so please explain to me so i can understand. I am trying but all the animations were run on first start page and i do not see it when i am on the first page.
is important for my project to school :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: thank for information ..i try :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>


<div class="wow bounceInLeft animated">
              <h2>animated heading</h2>
</div>
```

try this code...

[this link for more](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

Comment: okey i try and i have something download ? :)

Comment: finally worked very thanks bro :)

Answer (score 3):

[GITHUB](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

easy to use with this

download it and implement this in

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
</head>
```

then change class according to tutorial link above

```
<h1 class="animated infinite bounce">Example</h1>
```

(these classes can be used)

```
bounce
flash
pulse
rubberBand
shake
headShake
swing
tada
wobble
jello
bounceIn
bounceInDown
bounceInLeft
bounceInRight
bounceInUp
bounceOut
bounceOutDown
bounceOutLeft
bounceOutRight
bounceOutUp
fadeIn
fadeInDown
fadeInDownBig
fadeInLeft
fadeInLeftBig
fadeInRight
fadeInRightBig
fadeInUp
fadeInUpBig
fadeOut
fadeOutDown
fadeOutDownBig
fadeOutLeft
fadeOutLeftBig
fadeOutRight
fadeOutRightBig
fadeOutUp
fadeOutUpBig
flipInX
flipInY
flipOutX
flipOutY
lightSpeedIn
lightSpeedOut
rotateIn
rotateInDownLeft
rotateInDownRight
rotateInUpLeft
rotateInUpRight
rotateOut
rotateOutDownLeft
rotateOutDownRight
rotateOutUpLeft
rotateOutUpRight
hinge
rollIn
rollOut
zoomIn
zoomInDown
zoomInLeft
zoomInRight
zoomInUp
zoomOut
zoomOutDown
zoomOutLeft
zoomOutRight
zoomOutUp
slideInDown
slideInLeft
slideInRight
slideInUp
slideOutDown
slideOutLeft
slideOutRight
slideOutUp
```

Comment: thank a lot :) ..but i must download animate.min.css or all files :) on github

Comment: ok work :) thank ..but i need show animation only 1x when i scroll any section on page and not infinite how i set please ? :)

Comment: remove infinite that's it...
class="animated bounce"
good luck for your project :)

Comment: i have page which have example 5 section ... every section is on full screen so when i went see second section i must scroll down ...but animation start always when iam on first section ..but i have animation on section 2,3,4,5. i need run animation when i scroll to second section ,third section atd. :)..and thank :)

Comment: i put another code with **wow.min.js** put those in <head>